# Can PHP exclude the newline character when reading line by line?

Tags: php

I want to read line by line but I do not want to deal with newline, I want it to be removed so I only end up with the content of the line.

So right now my function is:

```
function getProductCount($path)
{
   $count = 0;

foreach (file($path) as $name) {
    if($name == "<product>\n")
    {
       $count = $count + 1;
    }
}
       return $count;
}
```

But ideally I would want to do:

```
function getProductCount($path)
{
   $count = 0;

foreach (file($path) as $name) {
    if($name == "<product>")
    {
       $count = $count + 1;
    }
}
       return $count;
}
```

Is there a way to also remove carriage returns too?

Thanks

Comment: If this in XML, you can use SimpleXML to deal with the file. Also, keep in mind that this code is not memory-efficient, better read the file line by line with fgets()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Look at the additional flags you can add to the function call. You should use "FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES"

Answer (score 4):

You can perform [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) on the line at the beginning of each loop iteration.

```
function getProductCount($path)
{
    $count = 0;

    foreach (file($path) as $raw_name) {
        $name = rtrim($raw_name);
        if($name == "<product>")
        {
            $count = $count + 1;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`trim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) or [`rtrim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)(if you want to preserve whitespaces in the beginning of the string) to strip whitespaces.

Answer (score -1):

you might want to look at: http://php.net/trim and http://php.net/str_replace (so you can replace the eol by an empty character)

Answer (score -2):

Either a regular expression (fetching the last occurence of \n in a line and stripping it) or simple `$name = substr($name, 0, -2)` would do the trick

Comment: or `$name = substr($name, 0, strpos($name, "\n"))`

Comment: Feels complicated and a bit convoluted. :-(